# What are the goals of Lean 4?

Tags: lean, lean4

Porting Mathlib from Lean 3 to Lean 4 is a huge effort, and I'm sure it's not undertaken on a whim. Could you please point me to documentation explaining the motivation for the incompatible changes? Is Lean 4 faster? More expressive?

The [Lean 4 survival guide for Lean 3 users](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/wiki/Lean-4-survival-guide-for-Lean-3-users) showcases many changes, but those look superficial to me.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question. Google search results are all fitness motivation videos and discussion of goals in the theorem proving sense. :(

Comment: Perhaps "leanprover" is a good search keyword. That's the downside of naming your language with a common word!

Comment: It looks like the port will be finished in a few weeks, by the way; the community is over 80% of the way through.

Comment: I saw! I wrote 71% in a doc a week or so ago and today it's 85%! Fantastic work! That's why I want to know exact _what_ I'm excited for! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many aspects to this:

- It's faster (e.g. the ~80% portion of mathlib that has been ported so far compiles between [3 and 4 *times* faster](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/287929-mathlib4/topic/port.20benchmark/near/364925768) than it did under Lean 3.)
- The metaprogramming framework (which is even more different relative to Lean 3 than the proving experience) is massively more capable. Most of Lean 4 is written in Lean 4, and users adding tactics can hook into and modify the internals in all sorts of new ways.
- It's intended as a general purpose programming language, not just an interactive theorem prover. (Lean 4 produces quite impressively fast executables. You can call into C++. It has [reference counting tricks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.05647) that allows functional code to be compiled to update-in-place when appropriate, and the [Do unchained](https://leanprover.github.io/papers/do.pdf) paper explains how to write functional code in an imperative style.)
- The type theory itself is essentially unchanged, although there are some usability improvements (in particular [typeclass search](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04301.pdf) is faster, and can cope with loops).